# List Full File Path of Multiple Files and Paste to Specific Column

Tags: excel, vba

I need help in changing the below code so I can get the full file path of the selected multiple files:

```
Dim xRow As Long
Dim xDirect$, xFname$, InitialFoldr$, xpaths  

InitialFoldr$ = "C:\" 'Startup folder to begin searching from
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\"
    .title = "Please select a folder to list Files from"
    .InitialFileName = InitialFoldr$
    .Show
If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
    xDirect$ = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    xFname$ = Dir(xDirect$, 7)
    Do While xFname$ <> ""
        Range("A2").Offset(xRow) = xFname$
        xRow = xRow + 1
        xFname$ = Dir
    Loop
End If
```

Comment: `Range("A2").Offset(xRow) = xDirect$ & xFname$ `

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim xRow As Long
Dim xDirect$, xFname$, InitialFoldr$, xpaths

InitialFoldr$ = "C:\" 'Startup folder to begin searching from
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
.InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\"
.Title = "Please select a folder to list Files from"
.InitialFileName = InitialFoldr$
.Show
If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
    xDirect$ = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    xFname$ = Dir(xDirect$, 7)
    Do While xFname$ <> ""
        Range("A2").Offset(xRow) = xDirect$ & xFname$
        xRow = xRow + 1
        xFname$ = Dir

    Loop
End If

End With
```